# How to make a List Column link to Excel Cell

Tags: excel

I have a SP library that lists the names of various excel spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet has a cell that reflects the percentage of completion for a project.

I also have a SP list of projects, which has a column for the % complete. Presently, that column has to be manually updated.

Can I put a column in my list of projects, that would link to the cell in the appropriate spreadsheet in the library, to reflect the up-to-date percentage of completion, so that it does not have to be entered manually every time? Can this be done without writing code? I am not a programmer type. Thank you. jbc